# Django: Make variable of child model depend on number of siblings associated with the same parent model at creaton time

Tags: python, django

Assume I have two models, one modelling a Patient and another one modelling a tissue sample. To avoid confusing among lab members, instead of refering to the samples and the patients by a PK we transform the PK into a hashed string named `displyed_id` below.

In the ideal case we would have a patient referred to as 'H6F4A' and the samples to be 'H6F4A-1', 'H6F4A-2', etc. (be labelled by a suffix of the sample number belonging to that patient).

As a requirement we would need that if a sample is deleted that the sample numbering doesn't change for the suceeding samples (as the samples have physical barcodes printed onto them).

As this is kind of hard to do (probably one would need a counter for every patient counting how many samples there are) we have opted to use the tissuesample pk as the suffix which is not really what we want as this is global and not per patient.

Even if this new counter would not be a pk, combined with the hashed id of its parent e.g. sample 1 of patient 1 being 'H6F4A-1' it would need to be an injective mapping as staff will always refer to this sample under this label.

Is there a nice way to achieve the above mentioned in Django without introducing potential bugs / race conditions?

Note that the system will be used by multiple pepople simultaneously i.e. in the worst case two samples are registered simultaneously which now is not a problem as the PK is guaranteed to be unique at insertion.

```py
class Patient(models.Model):
    ...
    displayed_id = models.CharField(max_length=512, editable=False)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.displayed_id = h_encode(self.pk)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class TissueSample(models.Model):
    ...
    displayed_id = models.CharField(max_length=512, editable=False)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        Patient,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )
  
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.displayed_id = str(self.patient.displayed_id) + '-' + str(self.pk)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly I might do it like this. Create a new field on the Patient model `max_tissue_id` which will increment after creating a new TissueSample and upon creation the TissueSample will take the `max_tissue_id + 1` from the Patient. Something like this should work:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    displayed_id = models.CharField(max_length=512, editable=False)
    max_tissue_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class TissueSample(models.Model):
    displayed_id = models.CharField(max_length=512, editable=False)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        Patient,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )
  
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.displayed_id = h_encode(self.patient.max_tissue_id + 1)
            self.patient.max_tissue_id += 1
            self.patient.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your ideal case, it is not necessary to have such a field on `TissueSample`. You can compute it on the run time.

For a single `TissueSample` instance, create a method to compute it like below. On each call, this method will hit the database at most twice: one for `rank` and another for `self.patient`. You can use Django's `@cached_property` decorator if this id is used multiple times in a rendering process, to save database connections.

```py
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class TissueSample(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        Patient,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )
    @cached_property
    def display_id(self):
        rank = self.patient.tissuesample_set.filter(pk__lte=self.pk).count()
        return f'{self.patient.display_id}-{rank}'
```

For a queryset of `TissueSample`, a window function need to be introduced

```py
from django.db.models import functions as fn, CharField, F, Value as V, Window

# e.g. a view to render all tissue samples for all patients
def tissue_sample_list_view(request):
    tissue_samples = TissueSample.objects.annotate(
        rank=Window(
            fn.RowNumber(),
            partition_by=F('patient')
            order_by='pk'
        )
    ).annotate(
        display_id=fn.Concat(
            F('patient__display_id'), 
            V('-'), 
            fn.Cast('rank', CharField())
        )
    )
    return render(...)
```

The code should be self-explanatory.

Please note that in above setup, deleting `TissueSample` instance may cause problems, especially ones that are not the last sample of a patient. You need to either prevent deleting `TissueSample` totally (use an `active` field to denote deletion instead), or be very careful (validate before deletion).